# ListBox virtualization not unloading items

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualization

I'm loading a lot of images in a listbox.
There was a sensible loading time before i tried to virtualize.

Now that i use virtualization only the elements that fall into view are loaded, exactly as i wanted; **but they don't seem to unload once they fall outside the view** so if i scroll all the way down to the bottom all the items are loaded and i lose the advantage of virtualizing.

Before i display any image, my app consumes 140MB, then i display 10 images and my memory usage equals 161MB, if i scroll to the last image the usage is 300MB. If 10 images use 21 MB, then with 300MB all the images must be loaded.

**This behavior is furthermore confirmed by inspecting the number of loaded ListBoxItems with Snoop.**

Nothing special in the code, i just make sure `CanContentScroll` is true to <del>enable</del> not disable virtualization. I customize the `ItemContainerStyle` and the template of the `ListBox` but it shouldn't affect the virtualization (or atleast not only the unloading part), isn't it?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}"  CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

Am I missing something?

**CONCLUSION**

The virtualization obviously works. Each ItemContainer is unloaded at some point when they fall outside the view.

The problem is probably how the BitmapImage caches. In facts, i'm using the following DataTemplate to show the images:

```
 <Image>
     <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding}" />
     </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```

Comment: In ***"they don't seem to unload"***, the word "seem" suggests that you're perceiving something in some way, which you interpret to mean that they're not "unloading". Can you be more specific about that, and about what you mean by "unload"? Are you just talking about the `Unloaded` event?

Comment: `CanContentScroll` enables virtualisation ? What about `<ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Of course: before i display any image, my app consumes 140MB then i display 10 images and my memory usage equals 161MB, if i scroll to the last image the usage is 300MB. If 10 images use 21 MB, then with 300MB all the images must be loaded.

Comment: @sam Thanks. That would be a great addition to the question.

Comment: @XAMlMAX CanContetScroll=False disables virtualization, so it must set to true to take advantage of virtualization. Google it. The other properties are set by default as you explicitly write.

Comment: Ah, that is something I never knew, thanks. I always used the explicit definition, but I also had to explicitly define the panel for the list view for it to work. like : `<ListView>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel></ListView>`

Comment: @XAMlMAX the default ItemsPanel in a listbox is a VirtualizingStackPanel

Comment: @sam Except memory consumption, how do you detect that item containers are not unloaded? Did you attach an Unloaded event handler?

Comment: @Clemens via Snoop i can see that ListBoxItems are always increasing in number. I'd expect a constant number of ListBoxItems.

Comment: Not sure how virtualization is supposed to determine when exactly an item container should be disposed of. You may still verify that this isn't just garbage collection coming late, by attaching an Unloaded handler. Also make sure that VirtualizationMode is not (for whatever reason) set to Recycling instead of Standard.

Comment: @Clemens i'm not sure where to attach the unload handler. ItemsPresenter, the scrollviewer the listbox itself? Can you please link me to an example?

Comment: With an EventSetter in the ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @Clemens yes, the unloaded event is called while scrolling

Comment: @Clemens To show images i'm using a DataTemplate which set the source via a BitmapImage. may BitmapImage not be unloading it's cache?

Comment: That's quite possible. You may try to set BitmapCreateOption.IgnoreImageCache to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on here is a memory leak problem with `BitmapImage` and `Stream`.
The problem is described [here](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream/)

The solution is to read the image through a `WrappingStream` as described and implemented [here](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2009/05/wrappingstream_implementation/)

Read the image like this and assign it to `Image.Source`:

```
  BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();

  using( var stream = new FileStream( uri, FileMode.Open ) )
  using( WrappingStream wrapper = new WrappingStream( stream ) )
  {
      bitmap.BeginInit();
      bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
      bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
      bitmap.EndInit();
      bitmap.Freeze();
 }

  return bitmap;
```

Comment: Good catch. I wasn't aware that this would also happen with a FileStream.